# HP DL380 G5 Predictive failure of a new drive

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

Consolidated Error Report:
   Controller: Smart Array P400 in slot 3
       Device: Physical Drive 1I:1:1
      Message: Predictive failure.

We have an HP DL380 G5 server with two 72GB 15k SAS drives configured in RAID1. A couple weeks ago, the server reported a drive failure on Drive 1. We replaced the drive with a brand new HDD -- same spares number. A few days ago, the server started reporting a predictive drive failure on the new drive, in the same bay.

Is it likely the new drive is bad... or more likely we have a bay failure problem?

This is a production server, so any advice would be appreciated. I have another spare drive, so I can hot swap it if this is a fluke and new drive is just bad.

THANKS!
CharlieJ

Comment: What does HP support, says? I expect you have carepack...

Comment: Using something so old (and unsupported) in production does not give me the warm fuzzies... if possible, I'd see about replacing it with something you have a support contract for.

Answer (score 4):

This is a Smart Array P400 controller, so the machine is of the ProLiant G5-era, placing it as more than three years-old and *out of standard warranty*.

Before going with another replacement drive, I'd suggest updating the firmware of your RAID controller, since misreporting is a symptom of some of the early firmware revisions ([changelog](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3288134&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D1121516%257CswItem%253DMTX-bc1046a3541a46389b7fa2d755%257CprodNameId%253D3288134%257CswEnvOID%253D4004%257CswLang%253D8%257Cmode%253D5%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken)).

You did not specify your operating system version, But the [Linux firmware is here](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=3288134&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodNameId%253D3288134%257CprodSeriesId%253D1121516%257CswLang%253D8%257CswEnvOID%253D4004%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken#29214) and the [Windows firmware is here](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=3288134&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodNameId%253D3288134%257CprodSeriesId%253D1121516%257CswLang%253D8%257CswEnvOID%253D4064%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken#29214). You will need a reboot.

If you're up-to-date on the firmware already, a power-off and power-on cycle (remove the power cables for a few minutes) may work to get things up again.

In general, firmware on HP ProLiant gear is key, so if you can spare the time (30 minutes), run the full bootable [Firmware update DVD](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=3288134&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodNameId%253D3288134%257CprodSeriesId%253D1121516%257CswLang%253D8%257CswEnvOID%253D4064%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken#2915) to bring BIOS, controllers, disks, ILO2, etc. to a more current revision level.

Answer (score 3):

It *could* just be bad luck but I have seen firmware issues on HP kit misdiagnose prefailed hardware before. What I suggest you should do is upgrade EVERY bit of firmware in the whole box, they make that easy now with those Proliant Pack things, just boot from the CD or .iso-over-iLO and it just runs, takes say 10-15 minutes and you then know the box is at a supportable level. Only then will you know for sure whether it's just a dead disk or not, that ok?